# "InternalIOException getAddrInfo: does not exist (error 10093)" on Windows 8

Tags: windows, http, haskell, conduit, http-conduit

Why is such simple code not working?

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main :: IO ()
main = simpleHttp "http://www.dir.bg/" >>= L.putStr
```

It results in the following error:

> TestConduit.exe: InternalIOException getAddrInfo: does not exist
>   (error 10093)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to use **withSocketsDo** to initialize sockets.
Like this:

```
import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Network (withSocketsDo)

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo
      $ simpleHttp "http://www.dir.bg/" >>= L.putStr
```

Comment: Actually, you should always use `withSocketsDo`, if on Windows or not. Then you'll never have this problem. :-)

Comment: I'm curious why this initialization is not happening behind the curtains or on-demand automatically?

Comment: @The_Ghost or designed so that well-typed code doesn't blow up, right? There's really no excuse for this kind of thing in haskell.

Comment: Yes, but we could put a lot of other stuff. We could brake withSocketsDo on parts and make people initialize it every time. I think this is non-sense. If there are a ways to make people write more correct code implicitly it will be better.